# Image out his View container

Tags: image, react-native

I have a View container of an Image component but my image is out of my view container ! I'm sure there is a prop solution for that but i dont remember[image]

I put a blue border to my container view with border radius and make 0.8 opacity with a red border to my image so that I can see my view container

Comment: ```style={{resizeMode: 'contain'}}``` try this. there are other enum values can be passed to resizeMode.

Comment: here it is https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode